# How to type an autocurry in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, typescript-typings, currying

I'm trying to write types for the following function:

```js
const curry = (
  f, arr = []
) => (...args) => (
  a => a.length >= f.length ?
    f(...a) :
    curry(f, a)
)([...arr, ...args]);
```

I found [this neat article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/typescript-curry-ramda-types-f747e99744ab/) that created a type for `curry` like this:

```
type Head<T extends any[]> =
  T extends [any, ...any[]]
  ? T[0]
  : never;

type Tail<T extends any[]> =
  ((...t: T) => any) extends ((_: any, ...tail: infer TT) => any)
  ? TT
  : [];

type HasTail<T extends any[]> =
  T extends ([] | [any])
  ? false
  : true;

type Curry<P extends any[], R> = 
  (arg: Head<P>) => HasTail<P> extends true
  ? Curry<Tail<P>, R>
  : R;
```

My problem is, this `Curry` type's signature does not match my `curry` function's (or are my TypeScript skills to bad and it does?). Additionally, I can't figure out how to write an implementation for `curry` that matches the `Curry` type.

How would one implement the types for my `curry`? And how would an implementation look like that uses the `Curry` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One major caveat here: [`Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) is weird; it's only going to behave well for functions without default or rest arguments.  For example, depending on what version of JS your TS compiler is targeting, you could get different answers for the following code:

```
console.log(((arg = 1) => { }).length); // 0? 1?
```

So keep that in mind when you use anything that depends on runtime reflection of function argument length.

---

Your `curry()` function is assignable to the `Curry` type definition, but not vice versa.  The `Curry` type definition expects exactly one argument each time it is called if the underlying function still needs arguments, whereas your `curry` will accept any number of arguments when it's called.  That means we can give `curry()` the `Curry` type, but the compiler will limit the number of arguments you call it with.  It could look like this:

```
function curry<P extends any[], R>(f: (...args: P) => R): Curry<Required<P>, R> {
  const _curry = (
    f: (...args: any) => any, arr: any[] = []
  ) => (...args: any) => (
    a => a.length >= f.length ?
      f(...a) :
      _curry(f, a)
  )([...arr, ...args]);
  return _curry(f);
}
```

Here we are essentially giving up on having the compiler do any real type checking inside the implementation; everything inside is more or less of the `any`type.  You might be able to get a little better type safety in there but not much; the compiler will not be able to verify the manipulations involved in appending to the end of a tuple type, and you'd end up using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) everywhere.

The `Required<P>` bit might not be necessary; it just depends on what you want to see happen for functions with optional arguments.  In general I'd be really careful using this on any functions of union types or whose argument lists can be different lengths, etc.

Let's just make sure the compiler is happy with a normal usage:

```
function test(x: string, y: number, z: boolean) {
  return z ? x : y;
}

const t0 = curry(test);
const t1 = t0("abc");
const t2 = t1(123);
const t3 = t2(true); 
console.log(t3); // abc
const t4 = t2(false);
console.log(t4); // 123
```

Looks good.

---

As for how you would make a TS typing for the full possibly-multiple-args-at-a-time version of `curry()`, it requires type level tuple concatenation, which is not currently directly supported ([see microsoft/TypeScript#5453](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453)).  You can write something that works involving recursive conditional types, but since recursive types are also not directly supported ([see microsoft/TypeScript#26980](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980)), I wouldn't recommend them for production systems.

Or you could pick some maximum length to support, like say, three arguments at a time, and write an version of `Curry` that works for that, but I don't know if it's really worth it:

```
type Curry3<P extends any[], R> = P extends [] ? R : (
  ((a0: Head<P>) => Curry3<Tail<P>, R>) & (
    P extends [any] ? unknown : (
      ((a0: Head<P>, a1: Head<Tail<P>>) => Curry3<Tail<Tail<P>>, R>) & (
        P extends [any, any] ? unknown : (
          ((a0: Head<P>, a1: Head<Tail<P>>, a2: Head<Tail<Tail<P>>>) =>
            Curry3<Tail<Tail<Tail<P>>>, R>)
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

especially because that particular definition uses [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) which might not play nicely everywhere.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhCGATAPAFShAHsCA7RAzlPLiANoC6AfFALwBQUU6WO+RZJIANFAHQCulCoygB+ZmQAMIpgC4ouCADcIAJwDc9eqEjN4ASwA2aDNjyFipSjQZMAFPYF9gC1AEo6NLp9YWijgD6Cly8zsCGRgoGuABm6sweXlYg7qISqKiiCpRaOuDQMPAEqJGmfuwpNnSiLOaV9pRQAD5QnKQUaUwSsfBGBBDZUMBqAK4QebrQAMKjamogyAAKZmyWQhS8AEq2ovbwagDmCnBIy1SetDRFJWVLNBWWI+Oi3VCz84ulxufbVK9QBRbPIAYwA9rgCGCjBA+EYwYdHPsjnQoABGS40ADeUAAvu44XhDsAABZdfJ6D4LADMy1W-iqmygO1RK0eHAo4mZgKg9j2+ykJwQKHumPecxpaDuVD+ngAZLyAWz6pZ2iBORJRrgANa4MEAd1wPL5TFNvIFQrO9148DRlpQ3xM9wuySpIFpjqlP2dsqgCpNZtNyrWHFCKQ1UC1uoNRoUAcDpsc8EFsGFv2IdtTZ09PuIACZ7V6TDmqKXMQCE0w3R6yp6S6XZRXTV1Ay2mC20u48vRYlqQcADBCoCCJYtgwyNn97LE484DocCAolmKtu4FG7kFsIABHUYGNQQEUy5nY0TgyHAKCBEefVHxqAz3lzo6LlJisMHNQhayc2htWRQGKTiCC+36pMk97wMk8CErgxIklAVB-rEsHweITaxMBfDwJ4chNteo7TjaHaNM+ahhCBC6dFoTAHsAcxGgRnzTl29C4toPZ9gOQ44AQwD2JgCh8WoMSHLwIAKLgowALYAEbqLwABeCiyWC0IILgnhYqIdEMVAilcpgPIgFo7HaOefHDFIqI3gs9i8cArEWZewBoqiwBSPYABE8CySCXlORClnAHm7lovYaJ5tSgUXsM1LuXm9ljBAMVQjCcIIvZ0UaFAAD0uXEH59DOcMAAsCXTn0AypepGWIsApVdnlBWRdSHG9rg-aDkaUJqMAADyuBoFQyJfpITLSfAYBxoJzBisJoktIoMnyeRUCIBABAghYoliCpakwiQWk6RA9FqEan58L1-ECeJYraWaJXSUZf6TWAAmsY9QWXtJICom99ipDRpq6edvLPVAyBQL9XIALRuQoMNQxDEgI1AUieAAVLyG1bTtcFw2jGLA-ipkcdoQA)